# Marshal flask for express js

Tags: express, marshalling, flask-restful

I'm looking for a module that do the same as [marshal](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/fields.html) for python flask restful.

Put object into a function and send it with good attributes as a json object.

Do you know something like that for node/express ? :)

Thanks !! Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, I made my own npm package. There it is: [marshalizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marshalizer)